# Preventing a missing or faulty plugin loaded inside of wp-settings from halting a script

Tags: plugins, scripts

```
foreach ( wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins() as $plugin ) {
    echo $plugin;
    wp_register_plugin_realpath( $plugin );
    include_once $plugin;

    /**
     * Fires once a single activated plugin has loaded.
     *
     * @since 5.1.0
     *
     * @param string $plugin Full path to the plugin's main file.
     */
    do_action( 'plugin_loaded', $plugin );
    echo 'end';
}
```

So I have a script that loads wp-settings and the script halts at: /var/www/public/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/w3-total-cache.php. I am thinking that do_action('plugin_loaded', $plugin); throws an exception and stops the script from running, how do you prevent an exception like that from halting a script? I tried to put a try catch, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If a plugin is crashing you need to contact that plugins support. You don't modify `wp-settings.php` under any circumstances, or any other WordPress core files, it is ***extreme bad practice***, and very dangerous. Bootstrapping WordPress in an external script is usually a sign that something is being done the wrong way too, e.g. being unaware of form handlers, REST endpoints, cron jobs, or WP CLI. Share some more information about what your script does and we can advise on the appropriate steps to take. Otherwise, you should never be in this situation

Comment: We're querying some type of posts on Wordpress and then running through some aggregation function to get some value at the end. It's a cronjob. It seems like we need to use some WP functions to make it run, so that's why they're doing it. What might be the thing preventing the script from running, and what are the alternatives if you need to query posts in a cronjob?

Comment: Have you looked into WP CLI commands? There's the WP Cron API too, but a system cron job that triggers a WP CLI custom command should do what you want without the problems you're encountering

Comment: Is it a php library? It looks like a linux library to enter bash commands.

Comment: It's a PHP CLI application, and a part of the official WP project. Browser requests can only run for so long before they hit the execution time limit and get killed. WP CLI allows you to add commands via your sites plugins for long running tasks. They also provide a lot of commands such as retrieving/adding/deleting posts, triggering WP Cron, etc. It also isn't Linux specific, and it isn't a library. I use it here on MacOS, I've used it on Windows in the past

Comment: Is there a short tutorial showing you how to convert a Wordpress cronjob to a PHP cli script?